# Disable rule & Create tags in sonar 6.7

Tags: sonarqube

How to disable rules in Sonar 6.7?

The deactivate button is not showing up in the newer Sonar (6.7).

How to create tags for projects in SonarQube 6.7?

Answer (score 2):

To edit rule inclusion in a profile you must have:

- [Administer Quality Profiles](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-GlobalPermissions) permission
- an editable profile

Since SonarQube 6.5, default profiles are no longer editable. Assuming you want a variation of the Sonar way profile, create a new profile, [copy the Sonar way rules into it](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-Copytherulesfromoneprofiletoanother?), and then remove the rules in question. Once you've marked your new profile the default, you're ready to go.